# didRangeBeacons method not getting called when display is Off

Tags: ios, background, ios7, uilocalnotification, ibeacon

i'm working with ibeacons from couple of weeks, i was trying to post some local notifications  , when the iphone hits the beaconregion(when proximity near).

It was working fine when the app  is in background with locked and with display on, but when my display turns black , 
didRangeBeacons method stopped getting called.

I know by using the

```
 region.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = true;
```

we can get notified while the display on.

Is there any way that i can achieve posting notification while the app is background with locked and display off.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 11):

It is totally possible to range beacons in background.

You can go around the limitation by setting this up together with your current location manager or creating a parallel one (which makes no difference, I think). You'll also need to enable background location updates capabilities at your project.

```
locationManager2 = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager2.delegate = self;
locationManager2.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer;
[locationManager2 startUpdatingLocation];

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{
     //Do nothing here, but enjoy ranging callbacks in background :-)
}
```

Now, you'll need to have a good explanation when Apple ask you why do you need the background location updates mode in your app. They're very picky with that.

Comment: Yeahhhh finally its happening , i have 10beacons in an array, was calling for all beacons in for loop for ranging, and finally it was ranging for the beacons even though my app is in locked state with sleep mode(i.e without light), what i have done is i tried with creating CLBeaconregion object for each loop of the proximity uuid and then passing that to [_locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:beaconRegionsObj];
[_locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:beaconRegionsObj];

Answer (score 4):

If you have requested both beacon entry notifications and ranging, and you ENTER a new region while the screen is locked, you will get a didEnterRegion message (or possibly the didDetermineState message) followed by about 5 seconds of ranging messages. If the user doesn't wake up the device during those 5 seconds, the ranging messages stop.

Thus you can't really filter based on proximity to a beacon from the background. If you try to wait until you get a range value of near then more than likely you won't get it because the device stops sending your ranging messages before the user gets that close. You then won't get any more notifications about that beacon region until the user either leaves the region again or wakes up the phone and brings your app back to the foreground.

An app I'm working on posts a local notification when it receives a didEnterRegion (or didDetermineState) message. That causes the screen to light up, but doesn't seem to extend the amount of time you get ranging notices.

Comment: Sounds like you were right at those 5 seconds of time, i will just make an alert like you just entered into a beacon Zone, then after the 5sec's i might get the notification when the light is on,i Will give a try with this. Thanks Duncan

Answer (score 2):

No, this is by design and reflects iOS's goal of conserving battery. You can only count on `didRangeBeacons:` while the app is foregrounded.

[David Young](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/11/13/ibeacon-monitoring-in-the-background-and-foreground.html) has a pretty thorough writeup that may help clarify.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem which Madhu has. Instead of **didUpdateToLocation**, I used **didUpdateLocations** which is worked for me. Now I am able to range beacons while the app is in background or terminated with locked and display off.

On **iOS 8.4**

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
    //Do nothing here
}
```